# Can I use Spring 5.0 with Tomcat 8.0 (not 8.5)?

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat8

Spring 5.0 release notes say it requires Tomcat 8.5+. [What's New in Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x)

Can you run Spring MVC 5.x on Tomcat 8.0? Is it just a matter of not being tested and officially supported, or is something broken? [Tomcat 8.0 to 8.5 migration guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html)

Tomcat 8.5 is supposed to be backwards compatible with Tomcat 8.0 and both versions support the same Java EE specification versions.

This is a different question than [Is upgrade to Spring 5 require Tomcat 8.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50970272/397408) because I want to know what features of Spring 5.0 require Tomcat 8.5 and do not work on Tomcat 8.0. I suspect that the "Web Reactive Framework" parts of Spring 5.0 would use the the non-blocking I/O improvements that were back-ported from Tomcat 9.0 to Tomcat 8.5. I think a Tomcat or Spring committer would likely need to comment on this.

**Motivation**

Ubuntu 16.04 inludes Tomcat 8.0 and not Tomcat 8.5. I don't think it will upgrade the tomcat8 package to 8.5 until it reaches end of life in April 2021. [Ubuntu xenial-updates tomcat8 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/java/tomcat8)

All this despite the fact that Tomcat 8.0 goes end of life in the upstream project in June 2018 replaced by Tomcat 8.5. [Tomcat which version](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) and [Apache Tomcat 8.0 end of life](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is upgrade to Spring 5 require Tomcat 8.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970272/is-upgrade-to-spring-5-require-tomcat-8-5)