# Does upgrade to Spring 5 require Tomcat 8.5+

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

Every tutorial for the upgrade to Spring 5 has tomcat 8.5+ as a requirement but no detailed explanation. The application that I want to upgrade should not run as a standalone application with an embedded webserver, but beeing deployed on a tomcat 6, which we cannot upgrade for several reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @procrastinate_later points out, [Spring 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x)  actually requires Servlet 3.1 (and Tomcat 8.5.x).

Spring 5 has initially was expected to have [Servlet 3.0](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/10/feedback-welcome-spring-5-system-requirements)+ minimum requirement which supported only from [tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

> We’ll definitely raise to Servlet 3.0+ (from our present Servlet 2.5 runtime compatibility)

So you need to upgrade to at least Tomcat 7.

Comment: Servlet 3.1 is required. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x.

Comment: @procrastinate_later updated my answer.please consider undo down vote

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [What's New in Spring Framework 5.x documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#whats-new-in-version-50):

> Java EE 7 API level required in Spring's corresponding features now.
>
> - Servlet 3.1, Bean Validation 1.1, JPA 2.1, JMS 2.0
> - Recent servers: e.g. Tomcat 8.5+, Jetty 9.4+, WildFly 10+

Cross-referencing this with the [Apache Tomcat Which Version documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), Tomcat 8.0 would be sufficient for the Servlet 3.1 requirement, but Tomcat 8.0 has been superseded by Tomcat 8.5+, as stated in the [Which Version (Tomcat 8.x) documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html#Apache_Tomcat_8.x):

> Tomcat 8.5 is thought as a replacement for Tomcat 8.0. Please refer to [Migration guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html) for guidance on migrating to Tomcat 8.5....Users of Tomcat 8.0 should be aware that Tomcat 8.0 has now reached [end of life](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html). Users of Tomcat 8.0.x should upgrade to Tomcat 8.5.x or later.